# Какие существуют на данный момент способы "горячей замены" кода в web приложении

Tags: java

Какие существуют на данный момент способы "горячей замены" кода в работающем java web приложении - желательно такие, которые не страшно использовать в продакшене? Какие есть у этих способов подводные камни и ограничения? 
Приложение представляет обычный war-рник

Comment: что такое `горячие замены`?

Comment: кода сервера/сервлета?

Comment: нет - не код сервлета. Допустим класс бизнес логики

Comment: горячая замена - т.е. заменить метод полностью или все методы класса. Или вообще новый экземпляр класса подсунуть - не останавливая приложение ни на секунду

Comment: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi_Specification_Implementations

Comment: [Патчинг Java кода на продакшене без анестезии](https://habr.com/ru/company/odnoklassniki/blog/429040/)

Comment: еще нашел может старую, но неплохую статью по поводу обновления классов через собственный загрузчик http://java-online.ru/java-classloader.xhtml