# Spring. Обновления во время выполнения приложения

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Я все не могу найти в документации хотя бы отложенного обновления конфигурации приложения во время выполнения (Сохранить состояние, обновить контекст и тому подобные штуки) без полной перезагрузки приложения и сохранения состояния в "файлик". Или это придется делать все в ручном режиме? На английской SO есть что-то такое, но в основном это перекрестные ссылки на друг друга без должного ответа.

Если иди очень четко, то есть web сервис. Он работает некоторое время и либо проверяет обновления, либо я передаю ему "что-то". Он сохраняет свое текущее состояние, полностью приводит весь контекст к необходимой конфигурации и восстанавливает данные. В голову приходит только файл или еще одно приложение, которое будет обновлять сервис. Мне сложно все это продумать, так как я не знаю возможности Spring в этой части. Т.е. я не знаю какими способами можно обновить удаленный сервис без его реальной перезагрузки, а это критично.

**UPDATE**
Уточную. Например, я создал новое API для приложения, которое не совместимо с предыдущим. Я думал про Spring Cloud: поднять новую версию, сохранить состояние предыдущей версии, убить старый сервис и передать сохраненное состояние новому (Меня вообще здесь все смущает). Горячая замена в данном случае мне не подходит, так как API может измениться.

**UPDATE**
БД пока не рассматривается, так как процесс approve проекта затянется на продолжительно время.

Comment: Не особо понял, что вам нужно обновлять во время работы приложения внутри приложения. Но есть такой формат файлов как .properties или cfg, в которые вы можете записывать свои данные в формате `name_param1=Myparam` и так далее, которые, спринг перечитывает. По идеи, налету

Comment: если Вас интересует горячая замена кода - задавал не так давно подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962930/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-web-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @dSH, горячая замена не подходит в данном случае.

Comment: @Dred, я хотел бы узнать, как происходят крупные обновления приложения на Spring и как сам Spring в этом случае поддерживает разработчиков. Я из мира плюсов, трудно придумать что-то лучшее чем файлы)

Comment: @MrBin, на основании вашего апдейта в вопросе, могу сказать только то, на основании моего опыта, если вы делаете большое обновление для приложения и в новой версии нет уже старого функционала, например, старых rest/soap запросов, то, обычно на прод выкладываются обе версии. Тут зависит от лояльности компании. Либо вы говорите клиентам, старый функционал мы не поддерживаем, обновляйтесь ( если есть мобильные приложения), либо никого не спрашивая, просто выкатываете обновления и всё. Перезапуск приложений всё равно требуется. Это, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос. В ответ это не вставляю, мало

Comment: Насколько важна бесперебойная работа? Можно ли выключить приложение и включить через несколько минут?

Answer (score 1):

Спринг вам здесь не поможет. Придется делать в ручную.

Обычно это делают так: разворачивают новую версию параллельно со старой, переключают трафик на новую версию и убивают старую.

Типичное спринг приложение хранит состояние в базе данных. Если миграция требует изменения в схеме то это отдельная песня.

Comment: Да, почему-то вчера в голову пришло про БД (Неожиданно, они СУЩЕСТВУЮТ). Но второй update.

Comment: А что у вас происходит если приложение или сервер падает? Данные теряются?

Comment: Я выбрал Spring как основу (А точнее стек Spring Cloud). Скажем так - это внутренний продукт. Но я сразу задумался о горячем обновлении, так как скорее всего все это в конце концов будет торчать наружу и будет мне недоступно напрямую (Таковы правила компании).

Comment: Дело в том что если у вашего приложение есть состояние, то его нужно где-то хранить и память не самое надежное место. Вам все равно придется придумать куда сохранять это состояние. Либо в файлы либо в базу либо еще куда то. Конечно все зависит от данных, но в подавляющем большинстве случаев база это лучший выбор.

Comment: Как я сказал раньше, то на подтверждение проекта уйдет слишком долго. Но ладно с данными. Интересен сам процесс обновления приложения (удаленно) без полной остановки приложения с использованием полной возможности java и Spring.

Comment: Это возможно, но так ни кто не делает :) Слишком много подводных камней.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92893/discussion-between-mrbin-and-talex).